# How to calculate distribution of spent time in a renewal process?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

So we are given an infinite supply of bulbs, following Exp($\lambda$)

You arrive at time t, note the bulb that is burning at time t.

$L_t$ = Lifetime of the bulb we noted

$A_t$= Lifetime of the noted bulb spent until time t

$B_t$ = Remaining lifetime of the noted bulb

I was able to calculate the distribution of the $L_t$, which came out as

P[$L_t \leq x$] = $1-((x\lambda + 1)* e^{-\lambda x}$ for $0<x\leq t$ and 1-(($t\lambda + 1)e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x \geq t$

I know $B_t$ follows Exp($\lambda$), which is the paradox.

How to calculate the distribution of $A_t$?

I was trying to use change of variable but because of dependent variable I was unable to proceed

Comment: Note that by the memoryless property, $A_t$ should also have $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ distribution.

Comment: I was thinking to apply it, but wasn't able to realize how to mathematically apply it.